# How can I ensure that my grid is never smaller than its child

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using a `grid` layout to stack elements in the z-direction. For some reason, if one of the child elements is very wide, it can stick out of the grid element:

```css
#z-stack {
    display: grid;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
#z-stack > * {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

#wide {
    width: 111vw;
    background: orange;
}

#tall {
    height: 111vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="z-stack">
    <div id="wide"></div>
    <div id="tall"></div>
</div>
```

You can see that the green border doesn't go all the way around the orange element, meaning that the child element is wider than the parent element. How can I make the parent element grow large enough to contain all its children?

Comment: Does "width: min-content" on the #z-stack solve your problem?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content

Comment: Or width: fit-content?

Comment: @DavidHänni Looks like it does! That was much simpler than I thought it'd be, thanks.

Comment: You can also use `display:inline-grid` (instead of `grid`). https://jsfiddle.net/y2esk69m/

Comment: You cannot have 111vh or 111vw. vh and vw are, by definition, 1% of the dimension of the viewport in that direction. That means the most you ought to have is 100vh or 100vw.

Comment: @fatpenguin it is quite OK to use more than 100 vw or vh units - it just means the element is wider than the viewport. So to see it all some scrolling will be needed, that’s fine. In this case it was useful as it ensured the child was wider than the grid element.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thanks, that's very helpful! I ended up running into problems with `fit-content` since it can't be combined with fixed sizes like `max(100px, fit-content)`. Not needing `fit-content` makes things much easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `min-width` property of the grid element to `min-width: fit-content`.

```css
#z-stack {
    display: grid;
    border: 5px solid green;
    min-width: fit-content;
}
#z-stack > * {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

#wide {
    width: 111vw;
    background: orange;
}

#tall {
    height: 111vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="z-stack">
    <div id="wide"></div>
    <div id="tall"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `display: grid` use `display: inline-grid`.

`inline-grid` allows the parent to track the length of the content.

`grid` simply takes up the length of the container.

Comment: Unfortunately this alone isn't enough... I've again found some children sticking out of their parent :/